# Интероперабельность C++ и Objective-C

Tags: c++, objective-c

1. Есть класс, написанный на C++. Могу ли я, реализовать эти методы в `.m` файле?
2. Есть класс, написанный на C++. Но он находится в `namespace`. В Objective-C такого нет. Тогда нужно использовать Objective-C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Иерархии классов в C++ и Objective-C (и даже Objective-C++) — несовместимы. Нельзя класс из одного языка унаследовать в другом. С помощью Objective-C++ вы можете написать обёртку, полагаясь на агрегацию и прочее. Полноценное взаимодействие с C++ тоже возможно только в Objective-C++.

Comment: Спасибо, значит все таки Objective-C++